# Disable a JavaScript function after it runs

Tags: javascript, function

I presume it is possible to create a JavaScript function that disables it self after it is done running.

Is possible? How can this effect be achieved?

Comment: Can you explain the use case? also what do you mean by disable?

Comment: do you mean a `javascript function` or do you really want to disable `a javascript`

Comment: IF you want to run function only once, you should look into `IIFE`. These functions are executed immediately and cannot be called.

Comment: i mean a JavaScript function.

Comment: Related: [Run javascript function only once](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23859916)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap arbitrary runnable in following manner:

```
function once(subject) {
   var first = true;
   return function() {
     if (first) {
        first = false;
        return subject();
     } else {
        return null;
     }
   };
}

var wrapper = once(function() {alert("No more!");});

wrapper(); // alerts
wrapper(); // noop
```

Runnable will only be executed on first invocation of wrapper.

You can [convert a function of arbitrary arguments to an argumentless runnable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17711245/125562).

Answer (score 2):

something like this?

```
function a(){ alert(1); a = null;}
```

invoke `a()` once, second time it will say

```
Uncaught TypeError: a is not a function
```

if the function is anonymous, then make it [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript)

```
(function(){ alert(1);})();
```

Comment: **Never give up**! :)

Comment: Will only work if function is stored in a field of original name. `var b = a; b(); b(); b();` will always alert.

Comment: @Basilevs agree, I guess if OP wants to execute it only once he/she wouldn't want to store its reference in another variable, but good catch!

Comment: @gurvinder372 we can even have named function as IIFEs. They will not be accessible but will add readability to code.

Comment: @Rajesh `we can even have named function as IIFEs` agree. but `add readability to code` debatable, not totally sure about that.

Comment: If you have multiple `IIFE`s then someone will have to read entire function just to get gist of function. In such cases, name would help. Yes we can add comments, but still I prefer having named IIFEs, even if its just one.

Comment: @Rajesh agree with readability part. But if one whole file is a function (check jquery source) then it doesn't make sense to name it, right?

Comment: @gurvinder372 Thats true. My point with single function was, if you have an initialize function, you can have a named IIFE there. But if it is used to encapsulate then it will not make much sense.

Comment: Why do you write `this.a = null` instead of `a = null`?

Comment: @Barmar then it will check variable `a` inside `function a()` and it won't set the function reference to `null`. You can try the same in console.

Comment: If you want to assign to a global variable, it should be `window.a = null;`

Comment: @Barmar true, but what if it is not a global variable?

Comment: Then `this.a` won't work, either, since `this` is `window` unless you're in an object context.

Comment: I just tried `function a() { a = null; }`, `a()` in the console, and after this `a` was null. There's no local binding of the function name inside itself.

Comment: @Barmar you are right. I don't know why `function a(){ alert(1); a = null;}` was alerting earlier multiple times. I have edited my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the functionality to be happen only once you can use the following function

```
function once(fn, context) { 
    var result;

    return function() { 
        if(fn) {
            result = fn.apply(context || this, arguments);
            fn = null;
        }

        return result;
    };
}

// Usage
var canOnlyFireOnce = once(function() {
    console.log('Fired!');
});

canOnlyFireOnce(); // "Fired!"
canOnlyFireOnce(); // nada
```

Courtesy: https://davidwalsh.name/essential-javascript-functions

Answer (score 1):

```
var _flag = true; // Have a flag variable.

function oneTimer(){

     // Check flag is set to true or not
     if(!_flag) return;
     _flag = false;

     // Your function definition here.


}
```

Comment: You are using a variable declared in the outer scope of the function, The accepted `once` functional decorator is a much better solution as everything is enclosed within it so there can be no issues with the 'pure' function. Also this would not be reusable, `once` can be used on any function, but if you wanted to do the same thing to another function you would have to do something like `_flag_2` which could get messy quickly.

Answer (score 1):

As commented, if you want to execute a function only once, you should try `IIFE`. These functions are invoked immediately and cannot be called afterwards.

Following is a sample code.

```js
(function test() {
  console.log("test");

  (function innerFunc() {
    console.log("Inner Function");
  })();

  try {
    innerFunc();
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex)
  }
})();

try {
  test();
} catch (ex) {
  console.log(ex)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty easy, just assign an empty function to the function:

```js
function once() {
    alert('once');
    once = function () { };
}

once();
once();
```