# How to restrict calling js appending functionality twice

Tags: javascript, html, function, append, stylesheet

I need to append the css and js file dynamically and am using below method

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild();
```

this method doesn't allow second parameter. 
I have to append both the css and js file dynamically. I am calling the above method twice to append the files. Any other generic way to restrict the above method to be called only once.

Here it is what i have tried:

```
var jscss = function(cp, sp){

    var css = document.createElement("link");
    css.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
    css.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
    css.setAttribute("href", cp);
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(css);

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = sp;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

};

jscss();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34672090/disable-a-javascript-function-after-it-runs/

Comment: `Any other generic way to restrict the above method to be called only once.` why do you want to restrict it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [documentfragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment) in order to only need to call to appendChild once to add both elements:

```
var jscss = function(cp, sp){

  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

  var css = document.createElement("link");
  css.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
  css.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
  css.setAttribute("href", cp);
  fragment.appendChild(css);
  //Does not affect the DOM

  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = sp;
  fragment.appendChild(script);
  //Does not affect the DOM

  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(fragment);
  //Adds both elements to the DOM
};

jscss();
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think you can achieve it by providing id to the element and before appending it just check if that element exists.
**Example:**

```
 var jscss = function(cp, sp){

    if(!document.getElementById("customStyleSheet")){
        var css = document.createElement("link");
        css.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
        css.setAttribute("id", "customStyleSheet");
        css.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
        css.setAttribute("href", cp);
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(css);
    }

    if(!document.getElementById("customScript")){
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = sp;
        script.id = "customScript";
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }

    };

    jscss();
```

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to remember if the function has run already.

```
var jscss_run = false;
function jscss(cp, sp) {
    if (jscss_run) {
        return; // don't run a second time
    }
    jscss_run = true;
    // do all the real work
}
```